# Code a File Path that works in both OSX and Windows (dotnet core)

Tags: macos, .net-core

I have to save files in my dotnet core application.  I originally developed in windows; but when I ported the code to try developing on a mac, the file path is no longer valid (i.e. "c:\content...").  Is there a way to reference a file path, in my code, that will work in both situations?  We deploy to azure... so the windows file path must there too.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("c:\\Content\\SalesOrderOutput\\" + 
      fileName.txt);
FileStream stream = fileInfo.OpenWrite();
```

Answer (score 11):

Use Path.Combine method like this:

```
internal static readonly FileInfo Mp4WithAudio = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources", "input.mp4"));
```

Code from https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/blob/c8cc4232b5afa2860ede3be63a680d754ed73002/Xabe.FFmpeg.Test/Resources.cs

Comment: Sorry for the dig but it appears that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `/`. I guess it is because the app is ran by visual studio in `./bin/Debug/net47/MyApp.app`, MyApp being the app package, so when the app is launched, the current dir is `/` ?

Comment: If you want to get current directory look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071639/c-sharp-get-assembly-executable-directory?rq=1